# How would I call and leave multiple people voicemail with Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio

I need to make an alert system that calls multiple numbers simultaneously and leaves them all voicemail.
How would I do this? Do I need to call every number one at a time

Comment: You would use Twilio APIs outbound calling method and iterate over a list of the numbers you want to call. I am not sure if the Twilio Outbound call method requires the call to finish before proceeding to the next one, but if it does, you can use python threading to bypass that.

Answer (score 1):

You can design this using the Twilio Call Resource. It is important for this use case to be in compliance with [TCPA guidelines](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-telephone-consumer-protection-act-tcpa).

Basically, you would [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) and enable [Answering Machine Detection (AMD)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) with `MachineDetection` set to `DetectMessageEnd`.

> If you would like to leave a voicemail on an answering machine, specify DetectMessageEnd. In that case, Twilio will return AnsweredBy immediately when a human is detected but for an answering machine, AnsweredBy is returned only once the end of the greeting is reached, usually indicated by a beep.

- Be aware each Twilio account has [1 Call Per Second (CPS)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180028-How-fast-can-I-place-or-receive-phone-calls-with-Twilio-). So calls will queue and then released at 1 CPS.